# why can't I to install boost in /usr/include?

Tags: c++, boost, build

I'm trying to install `boost` into include directory for avoid `-I` flag use in each g++ compiler call,I installed using this command line:  `./bjam --prefix=/usr/include install`
see `--prefix` value, it install in `/home/myusername`, why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running it as the root user, or some other user with permission to write to /usr/include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need root permissions to install in `/usr/include`.

Actually your system has done you a favor by not letting you do that.  The `--prefix` option says where to install *everything* -- headers, libraries, executables, documentation, etc.  For example, the header files would be installed in `/usr/include/include`, which is not going to be in your compiler's search path.

**Disclaimer:**: This assume that `./bjam --prefix=...` behaves similarly to `./configure --prefix=...`.  I haven't actually used `bjam`.  If `bjam`'s `--prefix` option means something else, please correct me.

Depending on your system, you may be able to install Boost from a repository rather than building it from source.  For Debian or Ubuntu, for example, something like `sudo apt-get install libboost` might work.

Note that I said something *like* that; it appears that Boost consists of a number of packages; `apt-cache search boost`, or better yet, do a Google search to see how to install Boost on your particular system.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo ./bjam
```

Doing this should run `bjam` with appropriate privileges to install to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`, both of which should be in your search path...